# MultiSelect in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown, multi-select

I am trying to implement the MultiSelect in react native. I have referred from  this link " https://github.com/toystars/react-native-multiple-select ". But unfortunately i am
not able to view the name in list of the drop down showing " No item to display ".

image:

[image]

For the name to be display in dropdown, data is taken from items prop which should be of the form of javascript array of object. Please help me out to solve this issue.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { SectionList, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, ListView, 
AsyncStorage, Button, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView  } 
from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import TextField from 'react-native-md-textinput';
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select'; 

export default class SendNotification extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
title: 'Send Notification',
};

constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
arr_user: [],           
} 
}

componentWillMount() {
this.getUsers();
};

getUsers = async () => {
const { page, seed } = this.state;
await fetch('.....api') 
  .then((response) => response.json()) 
  .then((responseJson) => { 
      
   this.setState({arr_user: responseJson.results});

 }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
  
   
};

focus () {
this.textInput && this.textInput.focus()
};  

onSelectedItemsChange = (selectedItems) => {

console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
this.setState({selected_user: JSON.stringify(selectedItems)});
};

render() {

return (
  
  <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#ffffff'}}>

    <ScrollView>
    
      <MultiSelect
        items={this.state.arr_user}
        uniqueKey="id"
        onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
        selectedItems={[]}
        selectText="Pick Users"
        searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Users..."
        tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
        tagBorderColor="#CCC"
        tagTextColor="#CCC"
        selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
        selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
        itemTextColor="#000"
        searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
        submitButtonColor="#CCC"
        submitButtonText="Submit"
      />

      </ScrollView>
  </View>

 );
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you mixing up async / await with the "classic" (fetch) promises syntax? So instead of writing

```
await fetch(YOUR_API) 
.then((response) => response.json()) 
.then((responseJson) => ...
```

you should write

```
... async () => {
   const  { page, seed } = this.state;
      try {
         const response = await fetch('..//api');
         const responseJson = await response.json();
         [DO CONDITIONAL CHECKS IF NEEDED]
         this.setState({ arr_user: responseJson });
      } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
      }
}
```

Otherwise you could write your fetch() the more classic way but without the "async/await"
Some usefull introduction into async/await was this article to me: [6 Reasons Why JavaScript’s Async/Await Blows Promises Away (Tutorial)](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)

Comment: I have tried but still it is not working...still the same issue " No item to display"

Comment: Have you debugged your `responseJson` maybe that response is wrapped in another object? Haven't used that <MultiSelect> component by myself, will try it later on.

Comment: Actually i am fetching the data from API in the JSON format, my data would be somewhat like this 
 [{"id":"14","name":"Ondo"},{"id":"15","name":"Ogun"},{"id":"16","name": "Calabar"}]

Comment: CORRECTED: Actually i am fetching the data from API in the JSON format, my data would be somewhat like this 
{"results":[{"id":"14","name":"Ondo"},{"id":"15","name":"Ogun"},{"id":"16","name": "Calabar"}]}
I dont know what i am doing wrong?!!

Comment: @AniketParab are you sure this isn't a typo issue? Based on the comment above, your API response comes with `results` whereas you are accessing `result` in the code you pasted below.

Comment: @MustaphaBabatunde  actually its a typo mistake. I have made the changes in code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which react native version you are using on that project. However componentWillMount is deprecated and will not work.
You can try with UNSAFE_componentWillMount or UNSAFE_componentDidMount instead.